# Usar TIMESTAMPDIFF na criação de tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Eu estou adicionando suporte a mysql para meu programa, atualmente só funciona com sql server, então me deparei com um problema com o mysql.

Tabela sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[login_user](
    [idx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [client_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Login] [datetime] NULL,
    [Logout] [datetime] NULL,
    [Time]  AS (datediff(second,[Login],[Logout])),
```

Tabela mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_user` (
  `idx` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` DATETIME NULL,
  `Logout` DATETIME NULL,
  `Time` AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,`login`,`Logout`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Bem a importação do tabela mysql não funciona pois parece n aceitar o TIMESTAMPDIFF, não quero ter que criar uma update no meu código para o campo `Time`, quero manter em tabela igual é no sql server.

Ao importar me mostra os seguintes erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que você precisará usar uma trigger para fazer isso. Mas tenta também retirar os apóstrofos dos campos na chamada da função, ou seja, usar *TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,Login,Logout)* ao invés de *TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,` login ` , ` Logout `)*

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa declarar o tipo que vai armazenar o resultado da função.

Veja os seguintes tutoriais:

- [How To Use The MySQL Generated Columns](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/)
- [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

A sintaxe correta é a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_user` (
  `idx` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` DATETIME NULL,
  `Logout` DATETIME NULL,
  `time` INT AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,`login`,`Logout`)),
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```